# How I can solve the SparkException for user defined function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

I want to apply linear Regression on dataset

```
val featureCols = Array("molecule_id", "group_id", "atom_id", "atom_id2", "mweight")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(featureCols).setOutputCol("features")
val df2 = assembler.transform(df)

val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("logp").setOutputCol("label")
val df3 = labelIndexer.fit(df2).transform(df2)

val Array(trainingData, testData)= df3.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2))

val linearRegression = new LinearRegression()
    .setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
val linearRegressionModel = linearRegression.fit(trainingData)
```

> 19/09/16 13:09:54 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 29.0
>   (TID 29) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user
>   defined function($anonfun$9: (string) => double)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)    at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:214)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1334)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$23.apply(RDD.scala:1139)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$23.apply(RDD.scala:1139)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1140)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1140)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Could you provide enough code to reproduce your problem? (in particular some way to generate data that looks like what you are manipulating)

Comment: thank you for replying. Error was due to a private method which was returning dataframe. I solved that by getting rid of that function